# Highcharts NG show only one point at a time. Animations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I want to show only one point at a time. As its the point transmission.

```
 var dataLength = $scope.performanceConfig.series[0].data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= dataLength; i++) {
                    appendBar(i,timeOutTime)
    }
  function appendBar(i) {

                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.fullScreenPerformanceConfig.series[0].data = [];
                    $scope.fullScreenPerformanceConfig.series[1].data = [];
                    $scope.fullScreenPerformanceConfig.series[0].data.push($scope.performanceConfig.series[0].data[i])
                    $scope.fullScreenPerformanceConfig.series[1].data.push($scope.performanceConfig.series[1].data[i])
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }, 500);
                }, 1000);
            }
```

By this method i have got the browser stuck. Which is the better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself :P

```
appendBar(0,dataLength);
function appendBar(i,dataLength) {
            var percentAge =(i / dataLength ) * 100;

                $timeout(function () {
                    if(i!=dataLength){
                        $scope.fullScreenPerformanceConfig.series = [];
                        angular.forEach($scope.performanceConfig.series, function (item, i) {
                            $scope.fullScreenPerformanceConfig.series.push({name: item.name, data: [],color:item.color});
                        });
                        $scope.fullScreenPerformanceConfig.series[0].data = [];
                        $scope.fullScreenPerformanceConfig.series[1].data = [];

                    }
                    $scope.fullScreenPerformanceConfig.series[0].data.push($scope.performanceConfig.series[0].data[i])
                    $scope.fullScreenPerformanceConfig.series[1].data.push($scope.performanceConfig.series[1].data[i])
                    $scope.barLoadStatus = Number(percentAge);
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope.$apply();
                        $scope.fullScreenChartConfig['chartObj'].redraw()
                    }, 100);
                    appendBar(i+1,dataLength);
                }, 1500);

        }
```